# Error while loading localhost where angular live development server is listening

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack, angular9

I'm getting the following error while accessing localhost where the angular development server is listening :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8kne.png)

ng serve is running as below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLZlA.png)

Can somebody help me out with this..
Thanks

Comment: Try a different port.  4200 is the default.  Possibly something else is running on 1200

Comment: tried with different ports...same  response